# Cakephp 3.x linking same table with join table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

This is my model

**messages table:**

message_id int, 
body varchar(50)

**messages_replies table:**

original_id int, reply_id int

As you can see I have a table of messages, whenever a user writes a comment it's saved here. But when a user replies a previous comment I want to save the new comment in the message table and which comment is replying in the message_replies table.

My problem is that I dont know how to link the tables in MessageTable.php because it references the same table.

This is what I've tried in MessagesTable.php :

```
$this->belongsToMany('Replies', [
          'className' => 'Messages',
            'foreignKey' => 'message_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'original_id',
            'joinTable' => 'messages_replies'
        ]);
```

And it fails in MessagesController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $messages = $this->Messages->find('all',['contain' => ['Replies']]);
        $this->set([
            'messages' => $messages,
            '_serialize' => ['messages']
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: am I wrong or a message can reply just to one message? So why belongsToMany? Do you actually need two tables?

Comment: It could be done with one table, but in that case there will be a nullable foreign key, and thats what Im ttrying to avoid.

Comment: Surely it should be `hasMany` replies, not `belongsToMany`?

Comment: So, what exactly is your issue? What does it means 'it fails in messageController'